# Using microsoft reportviewer 11 in visual studio 2005 project

Tags: visual-studio-2005, reportviewer

I am using report-viewer version 8 with visual studio 2005, works fine in development environment, but in the shared hosting environment it gives an error "The file has not been pre-compiled, and cannot be requested." This, I guess, is because the host server has support for report-viewer version 11.

Is it possible using report-viewer version 11 in visual studio 2005 project? Is there any other work around?